# Countdown timer pause/resume functionality javascript

Tags: javascript

I have implemented pause functionality, but for the life of me can't wrap my head around the resume functionality. The way this app is coded the seconds variable is reset to the value of the input. I think I have stared at this too long and cannot think of how to establish a resume feature.

```
    let seconds;
    let timer;
    let isRunning = false;
function start(){
        isRunning = !isRunning;
        if(isRunning == true) {
        seconds = document.getElementById("input").value;
        document.getElementById('count-down').innerHTML = seconds;
        timer = setInterval(check, 1000);
        } else {
            pause();
        }
    };
    function pause () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
function check() {
    if(seconds <= 0 ) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = "#80bfff";
    } else {
        seconds--;
        document.getElementById('count-down').innerHTML = seconds;
    }
};
</script>
    <div id = "timer">
        <div id="header">
            <p>Timer</p>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <p id="count-down"></p>
            <p class="inline">Enter time(in seconds)</p>
            <input class="inline" type="text" id="input">
            <button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you need to resume the timeout, you will somehow need to store the time left. I happened to have created the same functionality before. Take a look at the repo [here](https://github.com/yqlim/TimeoutControl/blob/master/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let seconds;
    let timer;
    let isRunning = false;
function start(){
        isRunning = !isRunning;
        if(isRunning == true) {
        seconds = seconds ? seconds : document.getElementById("input").value;
        document.getElementById('count-down').innerHTML = seconds;
        timer = setInterval(check, 1000);
        } else {
            pause();
        }
    };
 function pause () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
function stop(){
    pause();
    seconds = 0;
    isRunning = false;
  document.getElementById('count-down').innerHTML = seconds;
}
function check() {
    if(seconds <= 0 ) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        isRunning = false;
        document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = "#80bfff";
    } else {
        seconds--;
        document.getElementById('count-down').innerHTML = seconds;
    }
};




<div id = "timer">
            <div id="header">
                <p>Timer</p>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <p id="count-down"></p>
                <p class="inline">Enter time(in seconds)</p>
                <input class="inline" type="text" id="input">
                <button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
              <button type="button" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hit "resume" the variable `isRunning` is true and thus immediately afterwards the `seconds` variable is set to the value of the input element.

You can implement an extra boolean that checks if the timer started or has finished so that `seconds` is only set to the value of the input if the timer has not started/finished.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Unfortunately I didn't see them until after I completed the project. I'll post what my solution was incase someone needs it.

```
<div id = "timer">
        <div id="header">
            <p>Timer</p>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <p id="count-down"></p>
            <p class="inline">Enter time(in seconds)</p>
            <input class="inline" type="text" id="input">
            <br>
            <button type="button" id="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
            <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

    let seconds;
    let timer;
    let timeLeft = 0;
    let isRunning = false;
    let button = document.getElementById("button");
    let counter = document.getElementById("count-down");
    let body = document.getElementById("body");
    function start(){
            isRunning = !isRunning;
            if (isRunning == true && timeLeft > 0) {
                timer = setInterval(function(){check(timeLeft)}, 1000);
                button.innerHTML = "Pause";
            }
            else if(isRunning == true) {
            seconds = document.getElementById("input").value;
            counter.innerHTML = seconds;
            timer = setInterval(function(){check(seconds);}, 1000);
            button.innerHTML = "Pause"; 
            } else {
                pause();
                button.innerHTML = "Resume";
            }
        };
    function pause () {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        };
    function check(someTime) {
            if(someTime <= 0 ) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                body.style.backgroundColor = "#80bfff";
                setTimeout(reset, 5000);
            } else {
            someTime--;
            timeLeft--;
            seconds--;
            timeLeft = someTime;
            counter.innerHTML = someTime;
        }
    };
    function reset() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
        seconds = "";
        timeLeft = 0;
        isRunning = false;
        button.innerHTML = "Start";
        counter.innerHTML = "";
        body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
</script>
```